# How to make a regex to replace the value of a key in a json file

Tags: regex

I want to make a regex so I can do a "Search/Replace"
over a json file with many object.
Every object has a key named "resource"
containing a URL.

Take a look at these examples:

```
"resource":"http://www.img/qwer/123/image.jpg"

"resource":"io.nl.info/221/elephant.gif"

"resource":"simgur.com/icon.png"
```

I want to make a regex to replace the whole url with
a string like this: ***img/filename.format***.

This way, the result would be:

```
"resource":"img/image.jpg"

"resource":"img/elephant.gif"

"resource":"img/icon.png"
```

I'm just starting with regular expressions and I'm 
completely lost. I was thinking that one valid idea would
be to write something starting with this pattern *"resource":"*

and ending with the last five characters. But I don't even know how to try
that.

How could I write the regular expression?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
Find: "resource":\s*"[^"]+?([^\/"]+)"
Replace: "resource":"img/\1
```

Using `[^"]+?` ensures the match won't roll off the end of the current entry and gobble up too much input, and it's reluctant (with the added `?`) so it gets the whole image file name (instead ofwhat the last character).

#### Edit:

I added optional whitespace after the key, which your pastebin has.

See a [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/Taoi65VSbG) of this regex with your pastebin.

Comment: thanks Bohemian! There is something I don't get. When I try this in a file with one line like this: "resource":"http://www.img/qwer/123/image.jpg", then it works, but when I try it with a larger string like the one from this link http://pastebin.com/DVQSXJ5t there are no matches. Do you know what is happening?

Comment: I've improved the regex - try it now

Comment: thanks for the explanation Behemian! I tried the new regex but my text editor still says: "Can't find the text" with the larger string. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 5):

### [Regex](http://regex101.com/r/sJ4gG6)

```
.*\/
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/LPYC5UTxaBndwj3u)

This will find the text you want to replace.  Replace it with `img/` if you want to find the whole text you'll need to look for the following Regex:

```
("resource":").*\/
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/hvKw5BsTxwQfWPPi)

Then replace with `$1img/` this should give you group 1 and the img part.

Let me know if there are any questions

***Note:** I personally would just use objects since you have the JSON and parse it to a object then iterate over the objects and change each resource on each object independently rather than looking for a magic bullet*

Comment: This won't work except for the most trivial of cases due to the greedy quantifier

Comment: @Bohemian completely agree, hints my note. :)  I could make it more useful i suppose.

Answer (score 2):

If your JSON is an array of objects containing `resource` field I would do it in 3 steps: convert to object, find resources and replace them, convert back to string (optional)

```
var tmp = JSON.parse('<your json>');
for (i = 0; i < tmp.length; ++i) {
    for (e in tmp[i]) 
        if (e == 'resource') 
            tmp[i][e] = tmp[i][e].replace(/.*(?=img\/.*\..*)/,'') 
}
tmp = JSON.stringify(tmp);
```