# Regex to replace key & value in JSON

Tags: java, json, regex, parsing

I'm trying to remove the below key and valuefrom the JSON string in Java. I couldn't really crack the pattern. Can anyone help me find what I'm doing wrong here?

```
"appointment_request_id": "77bl5ii169daj0abqaowl0ggmnwxdk1219mug023", // (, included)
String newTransformedJsonString = jsonString.replaceAll("\"appointment_request_id\":\".*\",","");
```

I think I need to add a wildcard to make sure the starting and ending " for value are considered. I tried ?, surrounding the " as ["]. No luck.

- The value will never be empty.
- The value will have spaces trimmed
- Assume the value can have any character

```
{
    "appointment_request_id": "77bl5ii169daj0abqaowl0ggmnwxdk1219mug023",
    "app_spec_version": "0.0.61-5",
    "previous_invoice_ids": [
        "18000-A-qa4wl0kvka",
        "18101-A-y49daj0ppp"
    ],
    "contracts": [
        {
            "name": "bcbs.patient",
            "definitions": [
                {
                    "base_path": "/patient/v1",
                    "swagger": {
                        "swagger": "2.0",
                        "info": {
                            "version": "1.0.0",
                            "title": "patient-v1"
                        },
                        "basePath": "",
                        "tags": [
                            {
                                "name": "patient-v1",
                                "description": "PatientServiceResource"
                            }
                        ],
                        "schemes": [
                            "http"
                        ],
                        "webpages": {
                            "/patient/v1/insurace": {
                                "get": {
                                    "tags": [
                                        "patient-v1"
                                    ],
                                    "summary": "Returnsanerror,butwaitsbeforedoingso.",
                                    "operationId": "getInsurance",
                                    "produces": [
                                        "application/json"
                                    ],
                                    "parameters": [
                                        {
                                            "name": "statusCode",
                                            "in": "query",
                                            "description": "",
                                            "required": false,
                                            "type": "integer",
                                            "format": "int32"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Just use the `String#replace()` method instead of the `String#replaceAll()` method and regex: `.replace("\"appointment_request_id\": \"77bl5ii169daj0abqaowl0ggmnwxdk1219mug023\",", "")`.

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful.

[How to make a regex to replace the value of a key in a json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20691324/how-to-make-a-regex-to-replace-the-value-of-a-key-in-a-json-file)